# Multithread from within a class on C++11

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11

I have built a class called App. This is part of my traditional loop within my App::Loop function:

```
this->SwapBuffers(); 
this->Iterate(); // generate a new buffer 1 from buffer 0
this->Render();  // render the original buffer 0
```

And I can successfully get that to multithread with this code:

```
this->SwapBuffers();
std::thread t1 ( &App::Iterate, this );
std::thread t2 ( &App::Render, this );
t1.join();
t2.join();
```

But it actually runs a bit slower than the traditional code above (about 45fps vs 55fps).  I suspect it is because the thread calls copy the entire App class object and work on that copy each.  So, I've tried passing by reference:

```
std::thread t1 ( &App::Iterate, ref(this) );
std::thread t2 ( &App::Render, ref(this) );
```

But I get the compile message:

```
error: use of deleted function ‘void std::ref(const _Tp&&) [with _Tp = App*]’
```

I've been trying to understand the threading logic by following [this guide here](https://www.justsoftwaresolutions.co.uk/threading/multithreading-in-c++0x-part-3.html).

**How do I properly pass the class object in by reference?**

I am working in a Linux environment with GNU development tools.

Comment: Why would it be faster? I looks like you are creating two new threads every frame; threads are very expensive objects to create. Also, how does it even work, if 'Iterate' reads from buffer 0 while 'Render' writes to buffer 0, the code has undefined behaviour.

Comment: @Mankarse, Neither of those two threads write to buffer0. There was a reason I called SwapBuffers() before both of those Calls.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't need to pass the pointer to App as reference because the `this` pointer type `App*` has a small size (32/ 64 bit) which means it's preferrable to pass it **by value**.

When you pass `this` it is equal to passing App as reference because references get converted to pointers anyway.

---

Probably your delay happens because you create and destroy a thread at every rendering step.
Threads are heavy objects which require the OS to allocate a huge stack which probably causes the performance loss in your code.

Consider to reuse your threads through a **threadpool** or similar.

Comment: `std::bind` is unnecessary; the thread constructor already takes multiple parameters, and calls its first parameter with the values provided in the subsequent parameters.

Comment: I think the thread creation/destruction is the most likely culprit here.